# IOS7 cant find the CellLocation Table in consolidated.db

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, jailbreak

Hello I'm trying to find the tracking history of my Iphone 4 IOS 7.0.4.

Well I found the consolidated.db file in my local backup but there is no CellLocation table inside.

I used this example to find the neccessary data:

http://www.26horas.com/misc/apple-device-tracker/#instructions

My consolidated.db is looking like this:

[image: Consolidated.db Screenshot]

My Iphone Backup Browser Screenshot is looking like this:

[image: Iphone Backup Browser]

I also tried to find the cache_encryptedA.db file but cant find it.

Do anyone know how to find the celllocation table?

I'm using Windows 7.

Comment: There's `cache_encryptedA.db` file. It looks like tracking history is in there.

Comment: Well I tried to find the cache_encryptedA.db but not found it. Where is it located? I'm using Iphone Backup Browser to browse the files. I edited my post.

Comment: it's located in `/var/root/Library/Caches/locationd`. Use iFunBox instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't find it with iOS 7. The "CellLocation" table was removed in iOS 4.3.3 (short after it was discovered).

The iOS 4.3.3 update prevents location data being stored to backups, and the history of cached data (which is stored encrypted on the iPhone unless you opt-out from the feature) was reduced to seven days.

Sources: Plenty. Here is a github user's comment: https://github.com/petewarden/iPhoneTracker/issues/1#issuecomment-1566881
Here is an article from googling on the subject: http://www.pcworld.com/article/227171/apple_ios_update_removes_location_tracking.html